# C changing user

Tags: c, uid

Alright so my question is simple but I'm kinda new to C and I was hoping someone could help me. I want to change to a different user in C. For example, I know the user's password, and if the user types:
./change user1
It will change to user1. I know this may be a security issue right now, but I'm not worried about security at the moment.

Comment: In C, there is no such thing as a user.  That will depend on the operating system in use, and it's entirely possible that there will be no way to do what you want.

Comment: This question is highly dependent on operating system: What OS are you targeting?

Comment: Do you mean that when they use "`./change user1`", that the shell will now be in the other user? If so, there is already a tool for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use setuid which can be found in  `unistd.h` so it is available on POSIX systems (so any linux/unix falvour should be ok)

From the man page

> If  the  process  has  appropriate  privileges, setuid() shall set the real user ID,
>     effective user ID, and the saved set-user-ID of the calling process to uid.
>
> If the process does not have appropriate privileges, but uid is equal  to  the  real
>     user  ID  or the saved set-user-ID, setuid() shall set the effective user ID to uid;
>     the real user ID and saved set-user-ID shall remain unchanged.
>
> The setuid() function shall not affect the supplementary group list in any way.

here is an [example](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Setuid-Program-Example.html)

Comment: That only changes the user from the program's point-of-view though, doesn't it? i.e. the user reverts to the original user who called the program, and doesn't permanently change to the new user after the program has finished executing.

Comment: well yes. he would have to start some executable after the setuid for it actually to do anything useful

Answer (score 1):

Call the `su` binary (such as through `system()` or a combination of `fork()` and one of the `exec` functions), which knows about all the intricacies of changing credentials, both Unix-generically and on your particular OS. The terminal is shared and continues to belong to the original user.

Some of these intricacies not handled by a simple `setuid()` call are groups, account disabling and resource limits.

If this is just for fun, `setuid()` preceded by `setgid()` and `initgroups()` will probably be sufficient for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find out the UID using [getpwuid()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwuid). Afterwords you have to set the UID in your program with [setuid()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setuid) followed by the application/function you intent to run with these new rights, e.g. the shell. To start an application with the *current* UID use [system()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system).